# Firebase update Function is sometimes slower executed

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have a simple update function which sometimes executes really slow compared to other times.

```
// Five executions with very different execution times
Finished in 1068ms // Almost six times slower than the next execution
Finished in 184ms
Finished in 175ms
Finished in 854ms
Finished in 234ms
```

The Function is triggered from the frontend and doesn't run on Firebase Cloud Functions.

```js
const startAt = performance.now()
const db = firebase.firestore();
const ref = db.doc(`random/nested/document/${id}`);
ref.update({
        na: boolean // a calculated boolean with array.includes(...)
          ? firebase.firestore.FieldValue.arrayRemove(referenceId)
          : firebase.firestore.FieldValue.arrayUnion(referenceId)
      })
      .then(() => {
        let endAt = performance.now();
        console.log("Finished in " + (endAt - startAt) + "ms");
      });
```

Is there anything I can improve to fix these performance differences?

Also the longer execution times dont only appear when removing something from an array or adding something to an array. It appears on adding and removing. Sometimes these execution times go up to 3000ms.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Similar to cold-starting a Cloud Function where everything is spun up, initialized and made ready for use, a connection to Cloud Firestore also needs to be resolved through DNS, ID tokens need to be obtained to authenticate the request, a socket to the server opened and any handshakes are exchanged between the server and the SDK.

Any new operations on the database can make use of the previous work taken to initialize the connection and that is why they look like they are faster.

Showing this as loose pseudocode:

```
let connection = undefined;
function initConnectionToFirestore() {
  if (!connection) {
    await loadFirebaseConfig();
    await Promise.all([
      resolveIpAddressOfFirebaseAuth(),
      resolveIpAddressOfFirestoreInstance()
    ]);
    await getIdTokenFromFirebaseAuth();
    await addAuthenticationToRequest();
    connection = await openConnection();
  }
  return connection;
}

function doUpdate(...args) {
  const connection = await initConnectionToFirestore();
  // do the work
  connection.send(/* ... */);
}

await doUpdate() // has to do work of initConnectionToFirestore
await doUpdate() // reuses previous work
await doUpdate() // reuses previous work
await doUpdate() // reuses previous work
```

Comment: So is there nothing I can do from my side to improve the performance?
But the performance drops dont just appear at the very first update request or when I update several documents in a short time. It just randomly happens.

Comment: Aside from deploying resources and cloud functions closer to your users, I'm not currently aware of any way around it.